# Remove all but the highest value from a List grouped by another property using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a couple of classes that look like this (simplified for SO):

```
public class Result
{
    List<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
}

public class Review
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Amount { get; set; }
}
```

So the net result is we have a "Result" object that has a List<> of Review objects, each of which has a name and an amount. The "Name" property can be duplicated one or more times within this list.

Given a "Reviews" property that has several Review objects with duplicate names, I want to use LINQ to remove the "Review" objects with duplicate names from the list that have the lowest values (in other words, I want to remove all Review objects from the list EXCEPT for the one with the highest value).

So if my list looks like this:

```
Name      Amount
----------------
A              2
B              3
C              1
A              1
B              4
```

I want to use the LINQ `Remove` function on my list so that my end result is:

```
Name      Amount
----------------
A              2
C              1
B              4
```

Any suggestions on how do do this using LINQ? I'm looking for solutions on my own as well, just figured I'd post here to see if it's faster than figuring it out on my own. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a way you can do it :

```
var endResult = reviewList.OrderByDescending(e => e.Amount)
             .GroupBy(e => e.Name)
             .Select(g => g.First());
```